# NIntegrate failed to converge?

Tags: numerical-integration

Hey guys I have a pretty simple code that consists of an RMS calculation. The issue is that I am getting quite a few error messages when I run it. The following equations are highly published physics equations with confirmed results, so I am at a loss of why mathematica will not give me an answer:

```
lambda[z_] := Exp[-(z^2/2^2)]
fo[x_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[
1/(x - xprime)^(1/3) lambda'[xprime], {xprime, -Infinity, x}]
rms[y_] := 
Sqrt[NIntegrate[
lambda[x]*(fo[x])^2, {x, -y, y}] - (NIntegrate[
lambda[x]*(fo[x]), {x, -y, y}])^2]

rms[Infinity]
```

Comment: I get `0. + 1.52231 I` as answer, with no errors. What result are you expecting? And what Mathematica version are you using?

Comment: Sorry my apologies. When rms[0] to rms[100] is when I get the errors

Comment: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WZXQZ.png)

Comment: Interesting, do you mind explaining the plot a bit? Thank you.

Comment: On a Mac with v9.0.1 with fo restricted to numeric arguments, fo[x_?NumericQ], then for `Table[rms[x], {x, 0, 100, 10}]` I get 

{0., 0. + 1.52231 I, 0. + 1.52231 I, 0. + 1.52231 I, 0. + 1.52231 I, 
 0. + 1.52231 I, 0. + 1.52231 I, 0. + 1.52231 I, 0. + 1.52231 I, 
 0. + 1.52231 I, 0. + 1.52231 I}

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce an error when I try to evaluate

```
rms[500]
```

This results in the following error message

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one 
of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly
oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.`
```

The problem that you are facing is that, for large values of `x` the expression

```
1/(x - xprime)^(1/3) lambda'[xprime]
```

is strongly peaked around `xprime=0` due to the exponential in `lambda`. In addition there is a singularity at the upper limit. The integral over this expression, on the other hand, is almost zero and the singularity doesn't contribute to the integral. Mathematica has problems numerically integrating such a function because it doesn't know where it should refine the sampling for the integral.

If you look at your functions, you will notice that the Gaussian function `lambda` limits the interesting range to a couple of standard deviations. The value of `rms` doesn't change, once the argument goes beyond that range. This means that you can effectively, without noticeably losing accuracy, limit the argument of `rms`.

In the code below I have limited the integration range to 20σ.

```
sigma = 2;
lambda[z_] := Exp[-(z^2/sigma^2)]
fo[x_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  1/(x - xprime)^(1/3) lambda'[xprime], {xprime, -Infinity, x}] 
rms[y_] := 
 Sqrt[NIntegrate[
    lambda[x]*(fo[x])^2, {x, Max[-y, -20 sigma], 
     Min[y, 20 sigma]}] - (NIntegrate[
      lambda[x]*(fo[x]), {x, Max[-y, -20 sigma], Min[y, 20 sigma]}])^2]

rms[300]
```

Comment: This approach is the right direction, but same results can be achieved by forcing NIntegrate to start with a finer grid of regions using the options MinRecursion and MaxRecursion. The explanation in this answer is similar to the one in the section "Examples of Pathological Behavior" of the advanced NIntegrate documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#8354729 .